# Can't get form data to post using mySQLi

Tags: php, forms, post, mysqli

Almost identical to a previous question however I am now trying to use mySQLi to record some form data.

After I submit, the data does not post to the table. I've been reading through to the mySQLi documentation and some different videos but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

```
<?php

include('config.php');

if (
isset($_POST['store_id']) &&
isset($_POST['item_title']) &&
isset($_POST['date']) &&
isset($_POST['price'])
)

{

$store = get_post('store_id');
$item = get_post('item_title');
$date = get_post('date');
$price = get_post('price');


$query = "INSERT INTO ebay_data VALUES('".$store."', '".$item."', '".$date."', '".$price."')";

$input = $db_mysqli->query($query);



}

?>
```

Comment: Let's see... assuming the query succeeded... no error handling... using mysqli but not using prepared statements and/or placeholders... possible sql injection vulnerabilities (depending on what this `get_post()` function actually does...)... lack of any debugging (e.g. did you even try doing a `var_dump($_POST)` to see if your form data is even sent to the script properly?). etc... etc... etc...

Comment: try this:
$query = "INSERT INTO ebay_data VALUES($store, $item, $date, $price)";

Comment: @felips: that does absolutely nothing. `$x = 'foo' . $a` is functionally identical to `$x = "foo$a"`. all you've done is ... nothing.

Comment: wrap with quotes for each value, indeed

Comment: Marc - I am new to mySQLi with very minimal understanding of mySQL. I planned on creating a simple form that writes some information to a database and building on it as I become familiar with prepared statements and so on.

While your understanding of mySQLi is far greater than mine, not much of what you've said is actually helpful to me.

Comment: Try `var_dump($query)` to see what the query looks like. Add error checking; if `$db_mysqli->query()` returns false, `echo $db_mysqli->error;` to see the error message from MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to make sure your config is actually connecting of course. I typically just go to do it on one page if I get stuck, either way try:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', my_databasename);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf('Connect failed: %s\n', mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO ebay_data VALUES($store, $item, $date, $price)';
$mysqli->query($query);

printf ('New Record has id %d.\n', $mysqli->insert_id);

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

See if you get anything out on the page. Also should double check your post values are not empty. I have also ran into weird problems where setting the post to a var messed up sql queries, maybe try:

```
if (isset($_POST['store_id']) && isset($_POST['item_title']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['price']))

{
$query = "INSERT INTO ebay_data VALUES($_POST['store_id'], $_POST['item_title'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['price'])";
...
```

You also 100% need to check those post values, keeping your database and users safe. Prepared statements is a start. You do need a lot more than that though to keep it safe...
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Thanks for this. Before I am able to test I want to add that I am embedding the php tags within the html document. Will this formatting affect the way the data is retrieved?